# How to select html "ids" that are automatically generated by DevExpress constrols using Javascript DOM technique?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, devexpress

I want to create a pop-up that shows specific information related to hundreds of html divs (boxes) that have only class in common but specific id for each div automatically generated by DevExpress Controls.

I have hundreds of automatically generated html div "ids" how could I display each div specific information when I hover over that div using Javascript DOM techniques?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
    <div id="testDiv" onmouseover="alert(this.id)"> Alert on mouseover </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you trigger hover event on the classe of yours div, you get id with the event object

```
 var classname = document.getElementsByClassName("classname");

var myFunction = function(event) {
    var attribute = this.getAttribute("data-myattribute");
    var id = event.target.id
    alert(attribute);
};

for (var i = 0; i < classname.length; i++) {
    classname[i].addEventListener('mouseover', myFunction, false);
}
```